# Changing player names above head

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have been trying to create my own plugin with allows people to change their name that is displayed above their head, but I can't get it working.

My code:

```
public void NickPlayer(Player player) {
    try {
        String name = (String) main.getConfig().get("Nick" + player.getUniqueId());
        GameProfile playerProfile = ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().getProfile();
        Field ff = playerProfile.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
        ff.setAccessible(true);
        ff.set(playerProfile, name);
        player.sendMessage(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working" ?

Comment: It changes the name server-side, not player side, to that you need to send packets, but I don't know-how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing the `EntityPlayer` and it's GameProfile, you should use `PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo`. This packet should be sent to everyone who should show the name change.

For example :

```
EntityPlayer ep = ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle();
String name = (String) main.getConfig().get("Nick" + player.getUniqueId());
GameProfile playerProfile = ep.getProfile();
Field ff = playerProfile.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
ff.setAccessible(true);
ff.set(playerProfile, name);
// now the name is changed

for(Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
   PlayerConnection connection = ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle().playerConnection;
   connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, ep));
   connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, ep));
}
```

We could hope that the `EnumPlayerInfoAction.UPDATE_DISPLAYNAME` works but it's only the `entity.setDisplayName()` so it will not.

If this have issues, you can :

1. Just use Bukkit's method :

```
for(Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
   all.hidePlayer(p);
   all.showPlayer(p);
}
```

2. Try the hard way, by completly remove the player and make it respawn (only for players!) :

```
for(Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
   PlayerConnection connection = ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle().playerConnection;
   connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, ep));
   connection.sendPacket(PacketPlayOutEntityDestroy(ep.entityId));
   connection.sendPacket(PacketPlayOutNamedEntitySpawn(ep));
   connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, ep));
}
```

PS: You can add something like `Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater()` after removing and before adding, just to be sure everyone has removed the player.